# Is it possible to model one-to-many mappings in Yugabyte YCQL?

Tags: database, distributed-database, yugabytedb

For example,

```
key          | value
-------------+-------
primary_key1 | v1
primary_key1 | v2
```

Is the above allowed where the same key has multiple values? Or does one need to have an explicit clustering key? If I have a table with 2 columns, can the value be the clustering key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primary key has to be unique. It's how you distinguish rows from one another.
You can use for value a [collection column](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ycql/type_collection/) (map,set,list):

```
cqlsh> create table david.test(key TEXT, value SET<TEXT>, PRIMARY KEY(key));
cqlsh> insert into david.test(key,value) VALUES ('primary_key1', {'v1','v2'});
cqlsh> select * from david.test;

 key          | value
--------------+--------------
 primary_key1 | {'v1', 'v2'}
```

The other way is to add the [clustering key](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/api/ycql/ddl_create_table/). `key` will be the partition column, while `value` will be the clustering key (which will change the primary key to be `(key,value)`):

```
cqlsh> create table david.test(key TEXT, value TEXT, PRIMARY KEY((key), value)) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (value DESC);
cqlsh> insert into david.test(key,value) values('primary_key1', 'v1');
cqlsh> insert into david.test(key,value) values('primary_key1', 'v2');
cqlsh> select * from david.test;

 key          | value
--------------+-------
 primary_key1 |    v2
 primary_key1 |    v1
```

Here, `key` is the `partition value`. The `primary key` is (key,value);

Comment: Note that the recommended and more scalable way is option #2 - using the clustering columns. Here is another description with a simple example: https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/develop/learn/data-modeling/